# Port open but connection times out

Tags: java, linux, connection, port

I have set up a http server using java-based simpleframework (http://www.simpleframework.org/) on Linode - a linux hosting service. The server is supposed to accept connections on port 8080, but the connection times out.

According to netstat the server is listening on port 8080.

```
netstat -nl

Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN
```

Also web-based port checker http://ping.eu/port-chk/ says the port is open.

I can access the server from my linode - so the server appears to be running:

```
wget myserver.org:8080
```

gets me the html page.

However I cannot access the server over the internet, the connection times out.

The port is not blocked by any firewall as far as I can tell.

Any ideas?

Comment: How do you access it? What exact address do you use? The thing is that you could have DNS issues with your domain name - check it. Try to reach it with pure IP, not the DNS name.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! Using the IP address does not help, connection still times out. So I don't think it is a DNS issue.

Comment: Can the IP address, which you use, be seen from the internet or is this a VPN/LAN IP? BTW, when you check the connection via browser, is there anything written to the logs of the server?

Comment: IP address is the public IP address. Can access port 80 over internet using the IP address. As for server logs, I am not sure if logs are kept but I will have a look.

Comment: I just had another look at your netstat aaaaand.... your process on the 8080 port uses IPv6, not IPv4. Are you sure you want to run your process/service this way? As you can see - it doesn't have any foreign address attached as well, so it is pretty clear, why you cannot access it from the outside. You should check the config of the server that runs the service you want to reach.

Comment: Does it matter that the port uses IPv6 rather than IPv4? I can access port 80 fine. I took :::* in netstat output to mean "all foreign addresses". Is that incorrect?

Comment: Just IMO: you are trying to reach your server via IPv4 address from the outside and the tunneling to IPv6 simply doesn't work. Is there a way to start your server on IPv4 address and check it?

Comment: Although only tcp6 socket is listed in netstat, the server IS listening on both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses. Locally, wget http://127.0.0.1:8080 and wget http://[::1]:8080 both work. For some reason connections from outside are not being picked up, can't figure out why.